# Random set generation (with some parameter constraints)

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I have 8 readers for n number of scholarship applications. Each application will be read exactly twice. However, the same application cannot be read more than once by the same reader. I want to assign the applications to each reader, given the above constrains. How can I do that in R?

Example: 16 applications with 8 readers
reader1: 1,4,5,16
reader2: 1,6,10,11
reader3: 4,10,15,9
etc. until reader8:

Comment: i rewrote the question. it's my first time using the forum. i hope i wrote it clearly enough. thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to partition a vector composed of two copies each of the numbers from 1 to 68 into eight equal-sized (random) sets, try something like

```
split(sample(rep(1:68,2),rep(1:8,each=(2*68)/8))
```

This solution does not honor the additional constraint that *each subset should contain no duplicates*, i.e. each value should appear in each *subset* no more than once, and in the entire data set exactly twice.

The following function fails because it is likely that some values will not have been picked at all by the final step, which means the last sample will violate the constraints.

```
sampfun <- function(ngrp=8,ntot=68,mult=2) {
   n <- mult*ntot/ngrp 
   res <- list()
   all_chosen <- rep(FALSE,ntot)
   for (i in 1:ngrp) {
     res[[i]] <- sample(s[!all_chosen],size=n,replace=FALSE)
     all_chosen <- table(factor(unlist(res),levels=1:ntot))==mult
   }
   return(res)
}
```

Does your sample really need to be random?  You could just `split(rep(1:ntot,mult),rep(1:ngrp,each=ntot*mult/ngrp))` to partition the essays across readers, right?

Comment: Hi! Thank you! Let me explain what I'm actually trying to do. I have 8 readers for n number of scholarship applications (the range). Each reader will read a quarter of all the applications, and each application will be read exactly twice. However, I want each application to be read by any two readers, so that the readers are paired by application. Does that make sense. Example: If there are 16 applications and 8 readers it would be something randomly assigned as such:
reader1: 1,4,5,16
reader2: 1,6,10,11
reader3: 4,10,15, 9
etc. until reader8:

Comment: The applications do not need to be assigned randomly. The applications just need to be assigned as varied as possible across readers.

Comment: random assignment of applications to each reader was just so that each reader would have the least number of applications in common with another reader. In essence, that would discourage crosstalk about applications between readers.

Comment: Sorry if I explained my questions poorly. I edit it again in case anyone can help. Also, I saw code left by Ben Bolker. I tried 'split(rep(1:ntot,mult),ngrp)'. It didn't produce 8 sets. It just printed a list with the rage 1:68 printed out twice.